# When open softwareKeyBoard, bottom of layout has large space - Flutter

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

I have bellow source code, but when open softwareKeyBoard, bottom of layout has large space, I use from this code for height(`height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,`) but not work:

```
  SingleChildScrollView(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                   child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppColors.customWhite,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: AppColors.customWhite,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                      ),
                    ),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 10.0,
                          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.17,
                          right: 10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              const Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: IntrinsicWidth(
                                  child: Text(
                                    AppStrings.userName_0,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 22.0,
                                        color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 2,
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                  maxLength: 50,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      labelText: AppStrings.userName_1,
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                      filled: true,
                                      counterText: ""),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              const Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: IntrinsicWidth(
                                  child: Text(
                                    AppStrings.gender,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 22.0,
                                        color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 2,
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Radio(
                                      value: AppStrings.male,
                                      groupValue: gender,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        setState(
                                          () {
                                            gender = value.toString();
                                          },
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    const Text(AppStrings.male),
                                    Radio(
                                      value: AppStrings.female,
                                      groupValue: gender,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        setState(
                                          () {
                                            gender = value.toString();
                                          },
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    const Text(AppStrings.female),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              const Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: IntrinsicWidth(
                                  child: Text(
                                    AppStrings.birthday,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 22.0,
                                        color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 2,
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                  maxLength: 50,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      labelText: "...",
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                      filled: true,
                                      counterText: ""),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 0.0,
                                  top: 15.0,
                                  bottom: 15.0,
                                  right: 0.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                maxLength: 50,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                    labelText:
                                        AppStrings.identificationCode,
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    filled: true,
                                    counterText: ""),
                              )),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                            child: const Text(AppStrings.changeSaved),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want to use is MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom, this gives you the height of the keyboard when it is up. Here is how you can show the form distributed in the white space between the screen top and the keyboard top (or the bottom, when the keyboard is not there). You don't need the SingleChildScrollView (unless the height of all the widgets is greater than the white space). The Spacer widgets helps you to put the percentage of space you want from one widget to the next in the column. I replaced the AppString strings, so, replace it again.

```
Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.customWhite,
          border: Border.all(
            color: AppColors.customWhite,
          ),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
            topRight: Radius.circular(50),
          ),
        ),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 10.0,
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.14,
            right: 10.0,
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.14
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  const Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: IntrinsicWidth(
                      child: Text('UserName 0',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          color: Colors.black
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      maxLength: 50,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'UserName1',
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        filled: true,
                        counterText: ""
                      )
                    )
                  )
                ]
              ),
              const Spacer(flex: 1),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:
                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  const Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: IntrinsicWidth(
                      child: Text(
                        'Gender',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          color: Colors.black
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment:
                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Radio(
                          value: 'Male',
                          groupValue: gender,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(
                              () {
                                gender = value.toString();
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        const Text('Male'),
                        Radio(
                          value: 'Female',
                          groupValue: gender,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(
                              () {
                                gender = value.toString();
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        const Text('Female'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const Spacer(flex: 1),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:
                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  const Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: IntrinsicWidth(
                      child: Text('Birthday',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      maxLength: 50,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: "...",
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          filled: true,
                          counterText: ""),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const Spacer(flex: 2),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 0.0,
                    top: 15.0,
                    bottom: 15.0,
                    right: 0.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  maxLength: 50,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Identification',
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      filled: true,
                      counterText: ""),
                )
              ),
              const Spacer(flex: 1),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: AppColors.primary,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)
                ),
                child: const Text('Save'),
              )
            ]
          )
        )
      )
```